# Support Tooltip on the IMAGE Function?

Tags: formula, images, image-formula

Does the Image Formula field have Alt Text?

```
IF(Res_Date__c > NOW(), IMAGE("/img/msg_icons/confirm16.png", "All good"))
```

When the user hover over the Image I want to have a text display in my case it will be `All good`

Comment: Sorry - didn't notice until after I posted, the alternate_text is for when the image does not render. For reference, [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#IMAGE)

Answer (score 2):

Image formula does have Alt text and you are using it correctly. But your question was whether Image formula have any title attribute (which will be shown when you hover over the image)?

The answer is No. The workaround may to provide the title in helptext of the formula.

[image]

Comment: can you show the workaround you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry, helptext is not applicable to formula fields. My bad

Comment: @vigneshwaran I am sure you can create help text for a formula field :)

Comment: @Rao I was searching for that while providing the field name. Never went below check syntax button :)